# Unexpected graceful nginx shutdown

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

The following entries appear in a server's error log.

```
2022/09/19 23:31:29 [info] 192250#192250: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2022/09/19 23:31:31 [notice] 192254#192254: signal process started

[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.5287 165889/T6 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:670 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.5288 165889/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1245 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.5289 165889/Ta Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.5289 165889/Ta Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.5289 165889/T6 Ser/Server.h:901 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.5289 165889/T6 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2022-09-19 23:31:35.6368 165889/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
```

Resulting in the nginx service being inaccessible until manual restart.
This occurs once a day, minimum.

This is unexpected, as no action was put in place to initiate a shutdown action.

To compound matters, `crontab -e` should be monitoring for failures every minute
`*/1 * * * * /opt/launch-crashed-services.sh > /dev/null 2>`

Either the script is not firing or the script is not properly catching the failure. The designated log is empty.

```
service nginx status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        sudo service nginx restart > /var/log/nginx/relaunch.log  # /dev/null
fi
```

The main goal is to keep nginx up: how can one monitor that the cron job is firing?

But, the fact that nginx is receiving a command to shut down *gracefully* is **concerning** as well: what avenues of investigation should be followed?

**Update**

The service sometimes falls over really quickly:

```
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2022-09-25 05:03:16 UTC; 15min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 416872 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 416873 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 416885 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2339)
     Memory: 68.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service

Sep 25 04:50:33 sandbox systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 25 04:50:33 sandbox systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 25 05:03:16 sandbox systemd[1]: nginx.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Sep 25 05:03:16 sandbox systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 417241 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Sep 25 05:03:16 sandbox systemd[1]: nginx.service: Killing process 417241 (nginx) with signal SIGKILL.
Sep 25 05:03:16 sandbox systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Follows is the output of `nginx -T`

```
root@sandbox:~# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/10-mod-http-ndk.conf:
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-cache-purge.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-fancyindex.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-headers-more-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-lua.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-passenger.conf:
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_passenger_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-uploadprogress.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_uploadprogress_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-nchan.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_nchan_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf:
### Begin automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/jerdvo/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fidelity:
server {

  server_name sandbox.fdl.club;
  root /home/jerdvo/fidelity/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name fidelity_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sandbox.fdl.club/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sandbox.fdl.club/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = sandbox.fdl.club) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name sandbox.fdl.club;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/market_sandbox:
server {

  server_name provetp.sltfla.online proveat.sltfla.online;
  root /home/jerdvo/market/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name market_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }







    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/provetp.sltfla.online/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/provetp.sltfla.online/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

#  server_name prove_tp.sltfla.online prove_at.sltfla.online;


}
server {
    if ($host = proveat.sltfla.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = provetp.sltfla.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



  server_name provetp.sltfla.online proveat.sltfla.online;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/simon:
server {

  server_name simon.domayn.com;
  root /home/jerdvo/simon/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;

  location /cable {
    passenger_app_group_name simon_websocket;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
  }

  # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/simon.domayn.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/simon.domayn.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = simon.domayn.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



  server_name simon.domayn.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

**Update 2**
a systemd.service has a restart comand which is presently running.
The last restart has a timestamp [Sept28] found with the following snippet via `dmesg`:

```
[Sep27 23:05] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.524:32): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/17029/usr/lib/snapd/snap-co>
[  +0.000538] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.524:33): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/17029/usr/lib/snapd/snap-co>
[  +0.027718] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.552:34): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.005538] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.556:35): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.004074] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.560:36): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.003893] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.564:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.004513] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.568:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.006500] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.576:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.004354] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.580:40): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[  +0.003309] audit: type=1400 audit(1664319928.584:41): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" n>
[Sep28 00:24] show_signal_msg: 20 callbacks suppressed
[  +0.000008] nginx[56081]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f3350cda593 sp 00007fff52347cc0 error 4 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7f3350c72000+166000]
[  +0.000203] Code: 48 89 43 10 48 83 c4 18 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 0f 1f 40 00 0f b6 7f 30 48 c1 e8 03 48 29 f8 48 89 c3 74 89 48 8b 02 <4c> 8b 68 10 4d 85 >
[...]
[Sep30 02:01] nginx[208462]: segfault at 71 ip 00007f7b23ce3593 sp 00007ffede4fee10 error 4 in libperl.so.5.30.0[7f7b23c7b000+166000]
[  +0.000017] Code: 48 89 43 10 48 83 c4 18 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f c3 0f 1f 40 00 0f b6 7f 30 48 c1 e8 03 48 29 f8 48 89 c3 74 89 48 8b 02 <4c> 8b 68 10 4d 85 ed 0f 84 28 01 00 00 0f b6 40 30 49 c1 ed 03 49
```

Comment: The log snippet does not look like typical nginx log. Can you clarify the software setup more closely?

Comment: Question updated with a `service nginx status` output and that of `nginx -T`

Comment: It is the Passenger module that is shut down for some reason. By the log, it seems that something sends it the terminate signal. Have you monitored memory usage on the server? Maybe the process uses too much memory and kernel OOM killer acts as a result. You can confirm this by looking at `dmesg` output.

Comment: There is an entry with a timestamp associated wht a systemd restart.  Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in the Passenger module in your nginx, which is likely triggered by some part of your website code.

Try upgrading nginx and Passenger to most recent version and see if it becomes more stable.